# How can I limit access to the text format drop down in a paragraph?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I'm trying to limit the access for users to change the value of text format dropdown but I can't seem to find the correct dropdown to alter. Here's what I have so far but it seems to disable access to the field itself and not the text format dropdown.

```
function hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($element['#paragraph_type'] == 'my_paragraph_bundle') {
    $element['subform']['field_text_long']['widget'][0]['#format']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably need the module https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats. If you limit the allowed text formats to one the drop down will be disabled.

Comment: check my answer here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287223/how-to-set-the-default-format-in-text-format-and-hide-the-select/287242#287242  if you want to do it programmatically

Comment: check this https://berramou.com/blog/drupal-8-how-set-default-format-textformat-and-hide-select-programmatically